# NRVO. Turning off elision. C++11 vs C++17

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, return-value-optimization, nrvo

I am looking at copy elision and RVO/NRVO. When I run g++ with `-fno-elide-constructors` I see different behaviour for c++11 and c++17.

I understand that c++17 mandates RVO under certain circumstances. I would have assumed that the below counts as NRVO (unless the compiler first eliminates the named variable `y` too?)

```
struct rvo 
{       
        rvo () : val {0} { std::cout << "Default Constructor" << std::endl;};
        ~rvo (){ std::cout << "Destructor" << std::endl;        };
        rvo(const rvo& in){ std::cout << "Copy Constructor" << std::endl; }
        rvo(rvo&& in){ std::cout << "Move Constructor" << std::endl; }
        
        double val;
};

rvo f1(rvo& x){ 
        rvo y {x};
        y.val++;
        return y;
}

int main()
{
        rvo A{};
        rvo B {f1(A)};
        return 0;
}
```

Output when compiled up with no additional flags is as expected

```
Default Constructor
Copy Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

When compiled up with `-fno-elide-constructors` and `--std=c++11` the output is

```
Default Constructor
Copy Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

And this is fine as the temporary is being created.

My question is that when I compile up with `-fno-elide-constructors` and `--std=c++17`, it eliminates one of the moves.

```
Default Constructor
Copy Constructor
Move Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

It appears that it is eliminating the temporary return variable, and doing a move from the function variable `y` back to `B` in main. Even though I have switched off elision. Is it considering it as mandatory RVO or am I misunderstanding something basic?

I found this example, [RVO/NRVO can not be disabled in C++17 in Clang++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743861/rvo-nrvo-can-not-be-disabled-in-c17-in-clang) but that one is obvious RVO whereas I thought my example was NRVO and thus not mandatory.

Thanks very much if anyone can confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because from [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) there is [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and instead the object `B` is **created directly from the return value** `f(A)` so that there is no use of a move constructor or a copy ctor and hence the output.

This can be seen from [copy elision documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the **compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects**, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The **objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to.** The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:
>
> - **In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type** (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> ```

Comment: That is the question though. I thought my example was NRVO and thus not mandatory? Does the compiler first eliminate `y` as unnecessary and then apply the rule for RVO as a result.  But then where is the single move coming from?

Comment: @TCD: NRVO would eliminate the move constructor call. `y` still exists, and you know that because it is moved-from.

Comment: @TCD You're confusing the two move constructor calls. In particular, the first move constructor call is due to the return statement ``return y; which is what you have disabled using the flag. The second move constructor call is due to the creation of the object `B` from the returned prvalue and was not mandatory in c++11 but is mandatory from c++17.

Comment: @NicolBolas . Yes, I agree. But NRVO is not mandatory I think. Which is why I would not expect the `-fno-elide-constructors` to switch it off

Comment: @TCD: Switch *what* off? There are several operations here: the move from `y` to the prvalue return, the move from the prvalue return to `B`. The first is NRVO. The second is not. When you eliminate the second, you just have a move from `y` to the prvalue return, which now *is `B`*.

Comment: @TCD Again, the second move constructor call is due to the creation of the object `B` from the returned prvalue expression. The flag has no effect on this from c++17 because of mandatory copy elision. Note also that the first move constructor call was due to `return y;` which is what is disabled using the flag in both c++11 and c++17.

Comment: @JasonLiam So `y` is a prvalue? I thought it would be an lvalue, and then the return statement is optimised to do a move on it as it is going to expire

Comment: @TCD No, `y` is not a prvalue. It is an **lvalue**. Instead the expression `f(A)` is a prvalue. That is why i used the cppreference as it says; *"In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type"*

Comment: Thanks also to @JasonLiam. I appreciate it a lot